# Template conflict with WC Payment Method

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, templates

So, again I come here to ask you for help.

I'm using Apus RealState Template with WooCommerce.
Everything was fine til I installed a payment gateway module...

Now, Wordpress logs the following to the console with every page I try to load:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
>
> > at HTMLDocument. (erede.js:6)
> >       at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
> >        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
> >        at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
> >        at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>
> (anonymous) @ erede.js:6
>   i @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
>   fireWith @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
>   ready @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
>   K @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

This is the context mentioned from erede.js:

```
(function( $ ) {
'use strict';

$( function() {

    var checkIfInputHasDefaultBehavior = $("#checkInputClass").css("background-image").includes("url");

    if(!checkIfInputHasDefaultBehavior)
    {   
        return;
    }
```

but when I change the template, this error stops happening... does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: does erede.js belong to the template or the plugin? it could be a browser compatibility issue (does it support this method?) or it could be that that id is not being used. try using `var checkIfInputHasDefaultBehavior = $("#checkInputClass").length && $("#checkInputClass").css("background-image").includes("url");`.

Comment: hey man, thank you very much for replying! I thought it were a conflict between template/payment plugin, but actually it is between the theme and WooCommerce...
My payment methods box does not load fully (it loads, but it maintains a preloader overlaying/blocking the box). This only happens with the template mentioned...

Comment: did you try using the code i gave? did it help?

Comment: wow man, sorry I did not, cause then I got really desperate when that conflict between WooCommerce and the template happened.

but damn, I've just tested, and thanks man! tks a lot! it actually resolved the conflict between the plugin and the template, all the pages are loading perfeclty now, tks!

Comment: i'm adding it as an answer then :)

Comment: ok, tks :) but notice I've already edited the question, so now the main scope is the conflict between template and woocommerce

Comment: so there's another issue? i'm confused

Comment: sorry man, yep, there is another issue now... are you familiarized with WooCommerce?

Comment: if it's a completely different issue you should start a new question. as far as i can tell my answer addresses the problem described (since you said it removed the error mentioned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could either be a browser compatibility issue (does it support the `includes` method?) or it could be that the id `checkInputClass` is not being used. Change the first line of the js to the following to ensure the element exists before further checks are done:

```
var checkIfInputHasDefaultBehavior = $("#checkInputClass").length && $("#checkInputClass").css("background-image").includes("url"‌​);
```